# Prove: $\mathbb{Z}_p\times \mathbb{Z}_p$ Not Cyclic

Tags: group-theory

How can I prove that $\mathbb{Z}_p\times \mathbb{Z}_p$ is not cyclic saying that $gcd(p,p)=p$ satisfies something that cause it to be not cyclic?

Comment: Can you show that all the elements have order (at most) $p$? What number would appear as an order if the group were cyclic?

Comment: Perhaps explaining why $\mathbb{Z}_p \times \mathbb{Z}_q$ *is* cyclic (for distinct primes $p,q$) would help you see your way to the result you are seeking.

Comment: Pick an element $(g,h) \in \mathbb{Z}_p \times \mathbb{Z}_p$. Then $(g,h)^p := (g^p,h^p) = (1,1)$. Why is this enough to show that it's not cyclic?

Comment: @AlkaKadri we get $g^p=h^p=1$ why should get contradiction but it seems fine as the order of $(g,h)$ is $2$

Comment: @newhere The order of any element in a cyclic group should be the same as the order of the group. So if $\mathbb{Z}_p \times \mathbb{Z}_p$ was cyclic, there must exist an element with order $p^2$. The above shows, however, that the order of every element is less than or equal to $p$.